# ASP.NET Webapp Works as Full Website, but not as Application

Tags: windows, iis-7, asp.net, virtual-directory, directory

I have a fairly simple ASP.NET (targeting.NET 4.0) web app, which is used as a dynamic request form.  I have tested this and it is working as a Web Site within IIS 7 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.  However, this only is my testing environment.  I was getting ready to move it over to production (same IIS/OS) where it would be set up as an application under our main website.  Oddly it will not work as an application under a website even though it has all the same settings and the `web.config` has loaded all the same settings.  And my AppPool's settings mirror what was in the testing environment exactly.  Additionally, I'm using the same (domain) user for permissions as I used in the test environment when it was setup as a website instead of an application under another website.  Here is the structure of the main website & where we want the app:

Main Site --> Sitefinity CMS based site
    |
     --> Virtual Directory (hosting some static HTTP webforms)
           |
           --> Application (YOU ARE HERE)

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm having trouble finding info on this particular issue.  Can this not be done in the first place?  Can there be a possible compatibility issue I'm missing here?  If this can't be done is there any way to make it appear as if the application is running as a subpage of the main website?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what error you're seeing?

Comment: No error message per-se, but it appears to 404 and the main site says "Page Cannot Be Found" but I'm using a direct link to the inner application.  The URL appears to re-direct to the sitefinity error page.